# How to use a drop down list for a delete query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want my parameter at the query to be chosen by a drop down list.
I want it to be in a query and not in a form BTW.

this is the sql of the query:

```
DELETE תפקידים.[קוד תפקיד], תפקידים.[שם תפקיד], תפקידים.[תיאור תפקיד]
FROM תפקידים
WHERE (((תפקידים.[קוד תפקיד])=[הכנס קוד תפקיד]));
```

Right now it asks for a number (like it should) and it works fine, but I want the user to choose from a drop down list and not guess what is the number of the row he wants to delete.

Comment: and you want to do this in MS-access or any other application ?

Comment: Well, can't be done in Access query. Why not use code behind a form? Users should not work directly with tables and queries.

Comment: @June7 but delete querys don't show the user anything so how can I use them in a form? doesn't the user just see the bar to enter the criteria?

Comment: Why delete record? Most developers avoid design that allows routine deletion of records. Should be strong justification for deletion and even redundant verification record should be deleted.

Comment: @June7 when an employe get's fired or quits, if he wasn't at a good position in the company I don't need he's details anymore. obviasly to delete I will ask for a manager password.

Comment: No reason to maintain historical info? No statistical analysis that would need this data? Could just have a DateTerminated field that would indicate record is 'inactive'. Apply filter to exclude from queries.

Comment: @June7 that was a bad example, a good one is medical limitation/problems. Where I want to know if a player is injured and in what way. After the player heals and is good to play againI don't want the row saying he is injured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot construct a dropdown list in query WHERE clause. Options:

1. user deletes record on form by clicking keyboard or ribbon or right click delete
2. dynamic parameter in DELETE query object can reference combobox on form for user input - then run OpenQuery command in macro or VBA
3. construct SQL action statement in VBA which concatenates combobox to include user input
   `CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE fieldname = " & Me.comboboxname`

Don't need to list field names in a DELETE action because the entire record is deleted.